# When i click on cityname then all the hospitals of this city should be show in listview

Tags: android

I am new to android and learning about Json

I have two webservice................
In one service I have `city_name` and `city_id` and in another service i have `Hospital_name` and
`Hospital_id`

Now my task is first show the list of all cities in listview form first webservice
this is i have done now.

**My second task is that when i click on first city name assume i click on
newyork then all the hospital of newyork should me show in listview.**

Should I need another webservice or something else.

I have simply two webservices. Is it possible to do second task from these two 
services. please help me.

this is code in which i am showing cityname from first service in listview

```
 public class CityNameActivity extends ListActivity{
ListView list;

private ProgressDialog pDialog;
// URL to get Cities JSON
private static String url = "http://14.140.200.186/Hospital/get_city.php";
// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_CITIES = "Cities";
//private static final String TAG_ID = "id";
private static final String TAG_NAME = "city_name";
// Cities JSONArray
JSONArray Cities = null;
// Hashmap for ListView
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> citylist;
//ArrayList<String> citylist;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.cityname_activity_main);
    ListView listView=getListView();
    citylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
  // list.setOnClickListener(this);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {

            Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    Specialities_Activity.class);

            startActivity(in);}
        });
            new GetCities().execute();
        }
/**
 * Async task class to get json by making HTTP call
 * */
private class GetCities extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // Showing progress dialog
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(CityNameActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        // Creating service handler class instance
        ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();

        // Making a request to url and getting response
        String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url, ServiceHandler.GET);

        Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);

        if (jsonStr != null) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                // Getting JSON Array node
                Cities = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_CITIES);

                // looping through All Cities
                for (int i = 0; i < Cities.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = Cities.getJSONObject(i);

                    //String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                    String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                    HashMap<String, String> Cities = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    Cities.put(TAG_NAME, name);


                    // adding contact to Cities list
                    citylist.add(Cities);


                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result)
    {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        // Dismiss the progress dialog
        if (pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.dismiss();
        /**`enter code here`
         * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
         * */
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(CityNameActivity.this, citylist, R.layout.city_list_item, new String[] { TAG_NAME}, new int[] { R.id.name});
        setListAdapter(adapter);




    }
}
```

this is code in which i am showing list of hospital from second service

```
   public class HospitalList_Activity extends ListActivity {
private ProgressDialog pDialog;
// URL to get Hospitals JSON
private static String url = "http://14.140.200.186/hospital/get_hospital.php";
// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_HOSPITAL = "Hospitals";
//private static final String TAG_ID = "id";
private static final String TAG_NAME = "hospital_name";
// Hospitals JSONArray
JSONArray Hospitals = null;
// Hashmap for ListView
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> hospitallist;
//ArrayList<String> citylist;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_hospital_list_);
    ListView listView=getListView();
    hospitallist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {

            Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Specialities_Activity.class);
            startActivity(in);
        }
    });
    new GetHospitals().execute();
}
/**
 * Async task class to get json by making HTTP call
 * */
private class GetHospitals extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // Showing progress dialog
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(HospitalList_Activity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        // Creating service handler class instance
        ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();

        // Making a request to url and getting response
        String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url, ServiceHandler.GET);

        Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);

        if (jsonStr != null) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                // Getting JSON Array node
                Hospitals = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_HOSPITAL);

                // looping through All Cities
                for (int i = 0; i < Hospitals.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = Hospitals.getJSONObject(i);

                    //String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                    String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                    HashMap<String, String> Hospitals = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    Hospitals.put(TAG_NAME, name);


                    // adding contact to Cities list
                    hospitallist.add(Hospitals);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result)
    {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        // Dismiss the progress dialog
        if (pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.dismiss();
        /**`enter code here`
         * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
         * */
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(HospitalList_Activity.this, hospitallist, R.layout.hospital_list_item, new String[] { TAG_NAME}, new int[] { R.id.name});
        setListAdapter(adapter);




    }
}
```

Now i click on cityname name then all the hospital of that city should be open

Comment: @lfurini i am not asking people to do my work am jusking asking to how to do this

Comment: yes you have to get hospital name based on city name or city id. What you get in second service? only hospital name and id?

Comment: yes in second service i have hospital name and id only and in first service i have only city name and id and please give me short description how can i do this\

Answer (score 0):

Change the following...........
CityNameActivity class........

```
 public class CityNameActivity extends ListActivity{
ListView list;

private ProgressDialog pDialog;
// URL to get Cities JSON
private static String url = "http://14.140.200.186/Hospital/get_city.php";
// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_CITIES = "Cities";
//private static final String TAG_ID = "id";
private static final String TAG_NAME = "city_name";
// Cities JSONArray
JSONArray Cities = null;
// Hashmap for ListView
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> citylist;
//ArrayList<String> citylist;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.cityname_activity_main);
    ListView listView=getListView();
    citylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
  // list.setOnClickListener(this);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {

               String temp= citylist.get(position).get(TAG_ID);
         Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                Specialities_Activity.class);

        in.putExtra("city_id",temp);
        startActivity(in);}
        });
            new GetCities().execute();
        }
/**
 * Async task class to get json by making HTTP call
 * */
private class GetCities extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // Showing progress dialog
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(CityNameActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        // Creating service handler class instance
        ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();

        // Making a request to url and getting response
        String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url, ServiceHandler.GET);

        Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);

        if (jsonStr != null) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                // Getting JSON Array node
                Cities = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_CITIES);

                // looping through All Cities
                for (int i = 0; i < Cities.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = Cities.getJSONObject(i);

                    String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                    String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                    HashMap<String, String> Cities = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    Cities.put(TAG_ID, id);

                    Cities.put(TAG_NAME, name);



                    // adding contact to Cities list
                    citylist.add(Cities);


                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result)
    {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        // Dismiss the progress dialog
        if (pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.dismiss();
        /**`enter code here`
         * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
         * */
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(CityNameActivity.this, citylist, R.layout.city_list_item, new String[] { TAG_NAME}, new int[] { R.id.name});
        setListAdapter(adapter);




    }
}
```

Change in the HospitalActivity class........

```
public class HospitalList_Activity extends ListActivity {
private ProgressDialog pDialog;
// URL to get Hospitals JSON
private static String url = "http://14.140.200.186/hospital/get_hospital.php";
// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_HOSPITAL = "Hospitals";
private static final String TAG_ID = "id";
private static final String TAG_NAME = "hospital_name";
private static final String TAG_CITY_ID = "city_id";

// Hospitals JSONArray
JSONArray Hospitals = null;
// Hashmap for ListView
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> hospitallist;
//ArrayList<String> citylist;

String cid;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_hospital_list_);
    ListView listView=getListView();

    Intent in=getIntent;
    cid= intent.getExtra("city_id");

    hospitallist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {

            Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Specialities_Activity.class);
            startActivity(in);
        }
    });
    new GetHospitals().execute();
}
/**
 * Async task class to get json by making HTTP call
 * */
private class GetHospitals extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // Showing progress dialog
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(HospitalList_Activity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        // Creating service handler class instance
        ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();

        // Making a request to url and getting response
        String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url, ServiceHandler.GET);

        Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);

        if (jsonStr != null) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                // Getting JSON Array node
                Hospitals = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_HOSPITAL);

                // looping through All Cities
                for (int i = 0; i < Hospitals.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = Hospitals.getJSONObject(i);

                    String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                    String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                    String city_id = c.getString(TAG_CITY_ID);

                    HashMap<String, String> Hospitals = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    if(cid.equals(city_id)){                
                    Hospitals.put(TAG_NAME, name);
                     // adding contact to Cities list
                    hospitallist.add(Hospitals);
                     }



                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result)
    {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        // Dismiss the progress dialog
        if (pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.dismiss();
        /**`enter code here`
         * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
         * */
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(HospitalList_Activity.this, hospitallist, R.layout.hospital_list_item, new String[] { TAG_NAME}, new int[] { R.id.name});
        setListAdapter(adapter);




    }
}
```

Hope it will helpfull for u..

Comment: what are you saying i didn't understand

Comment: sorry,for this I editted  my answer

Answer (score 0):

Your second web service which returns a list of hospitals should accept city_id or city_name as a parameter. Now you only need to check which item on your ListView was clicked , get its Id and call your service with this.

Comment: from the second service i fetching only hospital names in another activity

Comment: Yes you should fetch hospital names for a specific city name/id. You can send selected id via Extras to your second activity and use it  there.

Comment: http://14.140.200.186/hospital/get_hospital.php . this webservice should accept  city name/id as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

on click of **city_name** pass *city_id* as parameter to you second webservice(which returns Hospital_name and Hospital_id) and then parse the data to the Listview

Comment: how can i do this please give me code because i am new to android so i am asking you to code please